# NSFetchedResultsController not fetching as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using following NSFetchedResultsController in my iOS app:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ToDoItems" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"tdText" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

To test it I am using following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int numero = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
    NSLog(@"Numero=",numero);
    switch (section)
    {
        case 2 : return numero;
        case 3 : return 30;
        default : return 8;
    }
}
```

I am sure, the entity ToDoItems has now 1 object (checked using SQLite Manager), but the NSLog shows `Numero=`
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: NSLog("numero %d", numero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your log is not correct as just said in my comment.

```
NSLog(@"numero = %d", numero);
```

Then you should implement correctly data source method of your table view. e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id  sectionInfo =
        [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

`numero` here is `[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]`.

For further info take a look to [NSFetchedResultsController tut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) and obviously to Core Data Programming Guide. It is your reference manual.

Comment: you are right, the log is not correct. But I need to keep the switch loop then there are fixed sections.

Comment: @mvasco So try your self...you have all the elements.

Comment: that's what I am doing,sorry, I have change my code to int numero = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]; but the result is the same 'Numero=0' and I am sure there is one object.

Comment: @mvasco no. `numero` is equal to `[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]`. So you need to use it in your second snippet.

Comment: @mvasco yes if data are in the store. My suggestion. Remove the cache, remove the app from simulator and run again.

Comment: that's the issue, there is one object in the store, but numero=0;

Comment: I have check it also on another computer, but still showing numero=0, and now there are 3 objects in the store ????

Comment: You should open a new question and add details there. With no details I cannot figure out what is  wrong. Anyway, I would start a test project with a simple table. In other words, you first should verify if a fresh app works or not with data you have. No tables with sections. Follow the tut I linked. @mvasco

Comment: Did you call `[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]` ?

Comment: This was the point @DuncanGroenewald. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually printing out the number in the NSLog statement

Use

```
NSLog(@"Numero=%d", numero)
```

Comment: you are right, the log is not correct.Please see @flexaddicted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve but if you want a UITableView with fixed sections and some parts populated from Core Data and other parts hard coded, perhaps like a sidebar menu, then you need to do something like the following.  Note that in the example below the items in the "Tasks and Deliverables" section are obtained from Core Data using the fetchedResultsController (however just a normal fetch would be fine but I was too lazy to remove the fetchedResultsController code!).  All I do is get an array of the results so I don't use any delegate methods.

The sections are defined in the sectionsArray and each sections items are contain in separate arrays and stored in a dictionary called sectionMenus.

Note also that I load a temporary menu item ("Loading, please wait...") while data is loading from Core Data (iCloud files may not have downloaded data yet).

Anyway take a look at the videos at this link to see what this 'menu' looks like when the app is running.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/when-to-enable-the-user-interface/

In the tableViewController .h file add a `sectionMenus` dictionary and `sectionsArray` array as shown below

```
    @interface MenuViewController : BaseMenuViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
        NSArray *sectionsArray;
        NSMutableDictionary *sectionMenus;
        bool _isLoaded;
    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *entityName;

@end
```

Now in the .m file you need to do something like this:

```
#define MENU_PROJECT            @"Project"
#define MENU_TASKS              @"Tasks and Deliverables"
#define MENU_FINANCE            @"Finance"
#define MENU_QUALITY            @"Quality"
#define MENU_IT_SYSTEMS         @"IT Systems"
#define MENU_ADMIN              @"Administration"

#define SUBMENU_SCOPE              @"Scope"
#define SUBMENU_LOADING            @"Loading, please wait..."

@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[self.openingViewController setFilesName:self.filesName];
    //[self.openingViewController setFilesDate:self.filesDate];

    // If we get menu's from the database set this to YES
    _isLoaded = NO;

    sectionMenus = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    sectionsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:MENU_PROJECT, MENU_TASKS, MENU_FINANCE, MENU_QUALITY, MENU_IT_SYSTEMS, MENU_ADMIN, nil];

    NSString * bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

    if ([bundleID isEqualToString:@"au.com.ossh.iProject2FreeiPad"])
    {
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:SUBMENU_SCOPE, nil] forKey:MENU_PROJECT];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:SUBMENU_LOADING, nil] forKey:MENU_TASKS];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Expenses", nil] forKey:MENU_FINANCE];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Issues", nil] forKey:MENU_QUALITY];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Applications", nil] forKey:MENU_IT_SYSTEMS];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"People", nil] forKey:MENU_ADMIN];
    } else {
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:SUBMENU_SCOPE, nil] forKey:MENU_PROJECT];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:SUBMENU_LOADING, nil] forKey:MENU_TASKS];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Expenses", @"Ongoing Costs", @"Timesheets", nil] forKey:MENU_FINANCE];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Issues", @"Risks", nil] forKey:MENU_QUALITY];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Applications", @"Interfaces", nil] forKey:MENU_IT_SYSTEMS];
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"People", @"Setup", nil] forKey:MENU_ADMIN];        
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.entityName = @"ProjectCategory";

    [self fetchedResultsController];

}

- (void)reload {
    NSArray *tadMenus = [self projectCategories];
    if (tadMenus) {
        _isLoaded = YES;
        [sectionMenus setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self projectCategories]] forKey:MENU_TASKS];
    } else {
        _isLoaded = NO;
    }
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
// Override this to set your own.
- (NSArray*)sortDescriptors
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortIndex" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    return sortDescriptors;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    /*
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    */

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[self sortDescriptors]];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (NSArray*)projectCategories {
    //LOG(@"projectCategories called");
    int count=0;
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo;

    if ([[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count] > 0) {
        sectionInfo = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] objectAtIndex:0];
        count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else
        count = 0;
    //FLOG(@" %d categories found", count);
    if (count == 0) return nil;

    NSMutableArray *projectCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];

    for (NSManagedObject *item in _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)
    {
        [projectCategories addObject:item];
        //FLOG(@" adding category %@", [item valueForKey:@"name"]);
    }

    return projectCategories;

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sectionsArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[sectionMenus objectForKey:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] description];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    static NSString *inactiveTableIdentifier = @"InactiveTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSObject *menuItem = [[sectionMenus objectForKey:[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *menu = [menuItem description];

    cell.textLabel.text = menu;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, what I am looking for is a tableView with fixed sections, fixed section titles, but all populated by core data objects.